# How to correctly bind images for use in Collection View in Xamarin.Forms (iOS project)

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms project where the interface includes a Collection View. However, when the iOS project runs, the images are not displayed on the iPhone. For Android, the images are displayed.

After some online research, I am aware that I need to include the image in the Assets file of the iOS project. I have tried many examples related to the ImageSource data structure. It did not work as I wanted.

So my question is how do I properly set everything up so that I can bind my location path of an image to the Collection View?

Here is a snippet of my Xaml source:

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=StatusTitle}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=StatusImage}" Scale="0.65"></Image>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsEnabled="True">
                                <Entry Text="{Binding Path=StatusValue}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="60" FlowDirection="MatchParent" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Large"></Entry>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Path=StatusUnit}" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is a snippet for the section of the code that populates the collection view (Note: There is some debug code in there that I will leave for reference only:

```
bodyTemp = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Temp", StatusImage = "weatherTest", StatusUnit = "F", StatusValue = "0" };
       /*         pressureData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Pressure", StatusUnit = "kPa", StatusImage = "barometer.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                humditiyData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Humidity", StatusUnit = "%RH", StatusImage = "humidity.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                lightData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "UVC Light", StatusUnit = "%", StatusImage = "lightbulb.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                fanSpeedData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Fan Speed", StatusUnit = "%", StatusImage = "fan.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                batteryData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Battery", StatusUnit = "%", StatusImage = "battery.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                heartRateData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Heart Rate", StatusUnit = "BPM", StatusImage = "heart.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                bosData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "BOS Rate", StatusUnit = "%", StatusImage = "oxygen.png", StatusValue = "0" };
                wifiData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Wifi", StatusUnit = "", StatusImage = "wifi.png", StatusValue = "Good" };
                bluetoothData = new DataObject { StatusTitle = "Bluetooth", StatusUnit = "", StatusImage = "bluetooth.png", StatusValue = "Good" }; */

                List<DataObject> dataArray = new List<DataObject>(10);
                dataArray.Add(bodyTemp);
           /*     dataArray.Add(pressureData);
                dataArray.Add(humditiyData);
                dataArray.Add(lightData);
                dataArray.Add(fanSpeedData);
                dataArray.Add(batteryData);
                dataArray.Add(heartRateData);
                dataArray.Add(bosData);
                dataArray.Add(wifiData);
                dataArray.Add(bluetoothData); */

                BindingContext = dataArray;
```

And here is the class definition of my data object:

```
class DataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged

{

private string p_Value = "0";

    public string StatusTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StatusImage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StatusUnit
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StatusValue
    {
        get { return p_Value; }
        set
        {
            if(value != p_Value)
            {
                p_Value = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusValue"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

}

Comment: for iOS, you can also place the images in the Resources folder, although Asset Catalogs are the preferred method

Comment: I do have the images in the Resources folder; however, I am still getting the same issue where the Collection view does not display the images. So they are both in the assets file and the resources folder

Comment: that's all you should have to do.  Have you looked at any of the Xamarin samples for comparison?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty much doing what they are doing in the examples

Answer (score 0):

Having a check with **[Local images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images)** this chapter .

- **iOS** - The preferred way to manage and support images since iOS 9 is to use **Asset Catalog Image** Sets, which should contain all of the versions of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors for an application. For more information, see [Adding Images to an Asset Catalog Image Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image).
- **Android** - Place images in the **Resources/drawable** directory with Build Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as **drawable-ldpi**, **drawable-hdpi**, and **drawable-xhdpi**).

**Note**:

Prior to iOS 9, images were typically placed in the **Resources** folder with **Build Action: BundleResource**. However, this method of working with images in an iOS app has been deprecated by Apple. For more information, see Image Sizes and Filenames.

**Therefore** , if setting `<Image Source="Saimiri_sciureus.jpg.jpg" />` in Xamrin Forms ,you will see the image in each platform as follow :

**Android** ：

[image]

**iOS** :(Using Asset Catalog)

[image]

or (Using Resource folder)

[image]

The effect :

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am doing that, my images are in the asset file. However, they are not appearing on the UI. I am trying to do data binding for the images on my collection view. I believe that the way I am doing the data binding is wrong. However, I can not seem to find an example that has the correct method.

Comment: @philm From shared code not finding problems with data binding .And if it works in Android , I think it's not related to data binding . If have a sample project link here, I will check that in my local site .